# Suppose $V=U\oplus W$; then show that $V^0=U^0\oplus W^0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V=U\oplus W$ then show that $V^0=U^0\oplus W^0.$ Here $V$ is a vector space and $U$ and $W$ are two subspaces of $V.$

My Attempt: We have to show that $V^0=U^0+W^0$ and that $U^0\cap W^0=\{0\}.$ Let $\phi\in U^0\cap W^0.$ Then this means that $\phi\in U^0$ and $\phi \in W^0.$ Which further means that for any $u\in U$ we have that $\phi(u)=0$ and similarly for any $w\in W$ we have that $\phi(w)=0.$ Now any $v\in V$ is of the form $v=u+w$ and so $\phi(v)=\phi(v)+\phi(w)=0.$ Thus for any $v\in V$ $\phi(v)=0$ and so $\phi=0.$ Thus $U^0\cap W^0=\{0\}.$ Now we have to show that $V^0=U^0+W^0.$ Let $\sigma \in V^0$ then $\sigma(v)=0$ for any $v\in V.$ We can write  $\sigma=\phi+\psi$ where $\phi(x)=\sigma(x),x\in U$ and $0$ otherwise and $\psi(x)=\sigma(x),x\in W$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\phi\in U^0$ and $\psi\in W^0.$ So $V^0\subset U^0+W^0.$ Now we pick $\sigma\in U^0+W^0.$ Then $\sigma(v)=(\phi_u+\psi_w)(u+w)=\phi_u(w)+\psi_w(u).$ What do I do after this step?

Comment: What is $V^0$ in this context? The dual space?

Comment: You probably wanted to say $V^*=U^0 \oplus W^0$.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be proved because it is not true. Suppose that $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, that $U=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and that $W=\{0\}\times\mathbb R$. Then $V^0=\{0\}$, but neither $U^0$ nor $W^0$ is equal to $\{0\}$. Therefore, $V^0\neq U^0\oplus W^0$.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your statement, as posted in the question, cannot be proven (see @JoseCarlosSantos' answer), the statement $V^*=U^0\oplus W^0$ *can* be proven, and you did well in proving that $U^0 \cap W^0 = \{0\}$.

Now, take any $f\in V^*$. Let $\pi_U, \pi_W$ be projections of $V$ onto $U$ and $W$, respectively ($\pi_U(u+w)=u, \pi_W(u+w)=w$ for all $u\in U, w\in W$). Note that $f(u+w)=f(\pi_U(u+w))+f(\pi_W(u+w))$ for all $u\in U, w\in W$, thus $f=(f\circ\pi_U) + (f\circ\pi_W)$. One can easily show that $f\circ\pi_U \in W^0$ and, similarly, $f\circ\pi_W \in U^0$, thus $f\in U^0+W^0$.